# Show results between daterange or show null values between selection criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to get a report to return results back, but currently getting incorrect/inconsistent results, which is causing me a bit of a headache.

A very simple snipped of the query I am using with all of it's data stripped out is as follows.

```sql
SELECT OCRD.CardName, OINV.DocTotal
FROM OCRD LEFT OUTER JOIN OINV ON OCRD.CardCode = OINV.CardCode
WHERE OINV.DocDate >= 'DATEFROM' AND OINV.DocDate <= 'DateTO'
```

As you would expect, this would return, customer name, and document values between the defined date range. However, I also want to include `NULL` values which also occur inside the date range?

(The idea behind it, is a nice simple report, customer/spend within a date range).

If I try to return `NULL` values, it shows only `NULL` values from the entire date range in the database. Is there a logical way for me to get this information?

---

Editing data from above to hopefully explain the results I am getting and the results i want to achieve... The value of my sales is pulling from the OINV.DocTotal, and the Date range is pulling from OINV.DocDate...
Using the data below; I am assuming that I am trying to show "NULL" Values, or "2019" dates.

**A) - Year 2018 - Sales of £100 | Year 2019 - Sales of £100 | Year of 2020 - Sales of £100**

The above would show a value of £100, because the year 2019 has sales of £100. This is perfect, and how I would expect the data to show.

**B) Year 2018 - NULL Sales | Year 2019 - NULL Sales | Year 2020 - NULL Sales**

The above would return a "NULL" Value; As the customer hasn't spent and it falls into the "NULL" Category. As above, this is how I would expect Null data to show.

**C) Year 2018 - £100 Sales | Year 2019 - NULL Sales | Year 2020 - £50 Sales**

The above line is my problem; Because my query is looking for a date of 2019, OR A NULL value, it doesn't show anything at all. (Because a data exists outside of my date range, and there is no values in the 2019 range) If this makes sense?

--- FURTHER EDIT ----

Shown below; In my report, if I put a date range of 2019, the 2x values "NULL" and "06/08/2018" will disappear from my report.. as if the customer doesn't exist.
I simply want it to show that they do actually exist, but just haven't purchased  in 2019.

[image: ExampleData]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Move the date condition into the join.

Comment: Null values from where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the date filter into the join condition you'll see the results you want. Never-spend customers will be treated exactly the same as those who've spent outside the desired range.

You'll see this particular problem all over Stack Overflow. It boils down to using a `where` clause against the inner side of an outer join. Moving the condition into the join changes the behavior to apply during application of the join rather than after.

```
SELECT OCRD.CardName, OINV.DocTotal
FROM OCRD LEFT OUTER JOIN OINV ON OCRD.CardCode = OINV.CardCode
    OINV.DocDate >= 'DATEFROM' AND OINV.DocDate <= 'DateTO'
```

You could also be more explicit about applying the filter first this way:

```
with FilteredInvoices as (
    SELECT * FROM OINV 
    OINV.DocDate >= 'DATEFROM' AND OINV.DocDate <= 'DateTO'
)
SELECT OCRD.CardName, OINV.DocTotal
FROM OCRD LEFT OUTER JOIN FilteredInvoices OINV ON
    ON OCRD.CardCode = OINV.CardCode;
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll have a look at this, I always love learning new techniques about SQL; It always amazes me how robust it is.

Answer (score 0):

By "NULL" values, I assume you mean all rows in `OCRD`, even when there is no match.  If that is the case, you can use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT OCRD.CardName, OINV.DocTotal
FROM OCRD LEFT JOIN
     OINV 
    ON OCRD.CardCode = OINV.CardCode AND
        OINV.DocDate >= 'DATEFROM' AND OINV.DocDate <= 'DateTO';
```

Note:  If `'DATEFROM'` and `'DATETO'` are being passed in from an application, you should use parameters.  You should not munge the query string with parameter values.

Comment: Sorry as i've just sat down with pen and paper i realised i didn't write left join on here.

I've edited, however with a left join it still isn't working for some reason.

Comment: @AndrewGray . . . Did you move the date conditions to the `ON` clause?

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, the `NULL` could be in the `DocDate` column and you want to include them into the result set. For that, you can try this:

```
SELECT OCRD.CardName, ISNULL(OINV.DocTotal, 0) DocTotal
FROM OCRD 
LEFT OUTER JOIN OINV ON OCRD.CardCode = OINV.CardCode
WHERE ISNULL(OINV.DocDate, 'DATEFROM') >= 'DATEFROM' AND OINV.DocDate <= 'DateTO'
```

Comment: The only issue with the above method i've just considered and came across; the value may not be a true "NULL" Value.. (It would possibly be a null value in some cases) in other cases, it would simply not exist in the date range i have chose. (so it wouldn't be a null value as such, it would be a non existent value) which I would want to show as zero.

Comment: As mentioned above, it's not exactly null values specifically... If my date range is 2019, I need it to show the values of the orders in 2019, if the customer has never ordered, it would show "Null" (or a zero value). if the customer has ordered in 2018, 2020 or 2021, i want it to ignore these sale values, and return zero (to show that the customer hasn't spent in 2019)

Comment: I am not fully clear what did you mean by "it would simply not exist in the date range i have chose". I updated the query a bit, please check that if it works for you. Other wise, it would be helpful to provide a solution if you could provide some example data from both the tables and explain the current output and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest results, however this is the query I have managed to get to work for me.  I've added the field "Type" in so you can see the results I am trying to achieve for each of my queries.

```
SELECT 'Range' AS 'Type', T0.CardCode, T1.DocTotal, T1.DocDate 
FROM OCRD T0 LEFT OUTER JOIN OINV T1 ON T1.CardCode = T0.CardCode 
WHERE T1.DocDate >= '2019-01-01' and T1.DocDate <= '2019-12-31'
UNION ALL

SELECT 'Null' AS 'Type', T0.CardCode, T1.DocTotal, T1.DocDate 
FROM OCRD T0 LEFT OUTER JOIN OINV T1 ON T1.CardCode = T0.CardCode 
WHERE T1.DocDate  IS NULL
UNION ALL

SELECT 'OutRange' AS ' Type', T0.CardCode, '0' AS 'DocTotal', T1.DocDate 
FROM OCRD T0 LEFT OUTER JOIN OINV T1 ON T1.CardCode = T0.CardCode
WHERE (T1.DocDate < '2019-01-01' OR T1.DocDate > '2019-12-31')

ORDER BY [TYPE]
`
```

Comment: I don't see any necessary to use the `WHERE` condition. Basically you are selecting all the records, isn't it?

Comment: I'm using the `WHERE` condition to bring the value of orders taken between the date range...
The ones which are outside of the `WHERE` Clause are replaced with '0' AS DocTotal

It's essentially a list of all customers within a specific postcode area; then their spends within a set date range.